# Angular binding third party js library event initialize

Tags: jquery, angular

Please suggest an solution for angular.

I have included bootstrap library js file in my angular application, now I want to bind its function to my elements on onotoalize but i am not able to do so. it says that the function is not defined. following is the event from bootstrap

```
ngOnInit() {


$('div').popover({
  html: true,
  trigger: 'hover',
  placement: 'bottom',
  content: function () {
    return $(this).find('.popover-data').html();
  }
});
}}
```

the error its giving is following.

```
ERROR TypeError: $(...).popover is not a function
```

But when i run this jquery code from developer chrome console it works fine, which means my bootstrap js is loaded with application

Comment: Use [ngBootstrap's Popover component](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples)

Comment: is there not any solution for this problem?